# How to use wmic in order to generate a txt with many columns

Tags: batch-file, wmic, text-manipulation, qfe

I'm using

```
    wmic qfe get HotFixID >> WindowsUpdateVersion.txt
```

in order to export a list of KB{num}. I am looking for a command to reshape this list in many columns (3 or 4 columns, .txt or .xls, not important).
I have already tried with

```
   wmic qfe get HotFixID /format:* >> WindowsUpdateVersion.txt
```

* (every WMIC Stylesheets)
but none of them seem to work properly.
Any ideas?
Thanks so much!

Comment: what means not work properly?see the available formats here: http://ss64.com/nt/wmicstylesheets.html

Comment: 'not work properly' means that none of the commands in the link you posted ( ss64.com/nt/wmicstylesheets.html) generates a .txt with more than one column. 
Thanks

Comment: On my screen the first two items are not in a format to place into columns.
`KB2899189_Microsoft-Windows-CameraCodec-Package` and `KB2868626`

Comment: Hi foxidrive. I am working on a workstation without camera, so I do not have a CameraCodec-Package. When I run my code, I obtain about 300 strings, 9 chars each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED: to process any trailing lines of less than `full` lines**

This creates `file.txt` with the ascii data and then writes `file2.txt` with the 4 columns.

Any lines containing `!` will be wrong - if someone wants to apply this in another situation.

```
@echo off
(
 for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('wmic qfe get HotFixID') do (
   for /f %%b in ("%%a") do echo %%~b
 )
)>file.txt

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set a=
set c=
(
 for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("file.txt") do (
  set a=!a! %%a
  set /a c+=1
  if !c! EQU 4 (
     echo !a:~1!
     set a=
     set c=
  )
 )
if not "!a!"=="" echo !a:~1!
)>file2.txt
```

Comment: @Matteo - No, there is a bug. It is not printing out the last line if it contains fewer than 4 entries. I believe it is a delayedExpansion issue, but there may be more to the story. Also, the ID widths may not be constant, so the columns may become misaligned.

Comment: @dbenham you are right: I confirm the issue about the last line! The misaligned it is not relevant if you import the file in excel

Comment: @dbenham Thanks for pointing out the bugs - I reused 2007 code which had a specific set of data and didn't study it to see that limitation.  I've replaced the code after testing it here briefly.

Comment: @Matteo Sorry about the bugs - mea culpa. Try the version above.